# List of ALL english words with english meaning

Tags: java, sql, text

I want an English to English dictionary for my java desktop application. Where can I get it?

Comment: This is question seems to be offtopic.

Comment: Why is this tagged with SQL? Do you have an SQL database of words that you want to check against a dictionary or do you have a (.txt) file with words that you want to check against the SQL-Database?

Comment: text file or SQL database both are helpful for me that's why i tagged sql...

Comment: if there is any java API which provides all words with meanings??

Answer (score 3):

You can get a copy of the [The Gutenberg Webster's Unabridged Dictionary by Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/673).